# Adding foreground color to an Iteml QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have an item which I've turned into a button with animations based on different states. The problem is, sometimes that button will be disabled and then I want it to have a semi-transparent foreground color to basically shade it out and signify that the button is disabled. Is there a way to do that to a QML Item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to add a Rectangle that is only visible if your button is disabled.

```
Item {
    id: button

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
        opacity: 0.3
        z: 2   // <-- Make sure it stays on top of the rest of the content
        visible: !button.enabled
    }
}
```